# javascript click all svg button modification request

Tags: javascript

i am trying to click on all white hearts only ignoring the red hearts that was done already.
i am trying to add a if statement to check but not sure how.

here is the code i have that clicks all hearts to red but stops clicking after certain period of time due to lazy loading on page so i need to re-click it so it resumes clicking.

```
const inputs =  document.querySelectorAll('.tiktok-1wyxwrs-DivLikeWrapper, .tiktok-ezxoskx1-DivLikeWrapper,.tiktok-1e3qwdr-DivLikeWrapper-StyledLikeWrapper,.tiktok-1e3qwdr-DivLikeWrapper-StyledLikeWrapper,.tiktok-1e3qwdr-DivLikeWrapper-StyledLikeWrapper')

for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {

  setTimeout(function() {
    inputs[i].click()
  }, 1000 * i);

}
```

ok so here is the javacode from browser for red hearts already done.

```
<svg width="20" data-e2e="" height="20" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="rgba(254, 44, 85, 1)" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g clip-path="url(#HeartFill_clip0)"><g filter="url(#HeartFill_filter0_d)"><path
```

and now white hearts

```
<svg width="20" data-e2e="" height="20" viewBox="0 0 48 48" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
```

ok so now i want to use my code and add a if statement to check if hearts have  **currentColor** then make red

this is my code that needs modification. need to add if statement to check for currentColor in loop code and click

```
const inputs =  document.querySelectorAll('.tiktok-1wyxwrs-DivLikeWrapper, .tiktok-ezxoskx1-DivLikeWrapper,.tiktok-1e3qwdr-DivLikeWrapper-StyledLikeWrapper,.tiktok-1e3qwdr-DivLikeWrapper-StyledLikeWrapper,.tiktok-1e3qwdr-DivLikeWrapper-StyledLikeWrapper')

for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {

  setTimeout(function() {
    inputs[i].click()
  }, 1000 * i);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below:

```
const inputs =  document.querySelectorAll('.tiktok-1wyxwrs-DivLikeWrapper, .tiktok-ezxoskx1-DivLikeWrapper,.tiktok-1e3qwdr-DivLikeWrapper-StyledLikeWrapper,.tiktok-1e3qwdr-DivLikeWrapper-StyledLikeWrapper,.tiktok-1e3qwdr-DivLikeWrapper-StyledLikeWrapper')

for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  if (inputs[i].querySelector('svg').getAttribute('fill') === 'currentColor') {
    setTimeout(function() {
      inputs[i].click()
    }, 1000 * i);
  }
}
```